# client_side_validations doesn't work - validations-hash is always empty :(

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm on the 3-1-stable branch of the gem. don't know if it's a bug or my stupidity.
client_side_validations just won't recognize my validations.

here's my code:

```
# model models/fan.rb
class Fan < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :email, :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end

# initializer initializers/client_side_validations.rb
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  unless html_tag =~ /^<label/
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}"                 class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
  else
    %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
  end
end

# view fans/new.haml
= form_for @fan, validate: true do |f|
    = f.text_field 'name'
    = f.email_field 'email'
    = f.submit

# application.js
//= require jquery
//= require rails.validations

# gemfile
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'client_side_validations', git: 'https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git', branch: '3-1-stable'
gem 'coffee-filter'
gem 'devise'
gem 'draper'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'heroku'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
gem 'paperclip-meta', :git => "git://github.com/dce/paperclip-meta.git"
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'thin'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'powder'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'sprite-factory'
end
```

i can submit the form (which i shouldn't be able to). the validations work (rails gives me be back the expected messages).
i tried debugging it by scanning the gem-code and i found out that a script-tag is inserted after every form that has validations.
my problem is that window[form.id].validators is always empty.

i use the normal form-builder. i tried stripping down all other scripts/styles/html until i only had the form and the required javascripts (jquery and rails.validations) but it just won't work.

any help is greatly appreciated :(

Comment: Don't know much about haml, but shouldnt `validate: true` be `:validate => true` ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
<%= form_for @merchants_list, :url => {:controller => 'merchants_lists', :action => 'create'},:html => {:id => "merchants_details_form",:multipart => true},:validate => true do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using client_side_validation gem Its is recommended to write Jquery_rails before  client_side_validation in your Gemfile. C_S_V gem using Jquery Ajax to validate.
Nothing else to do. Its an awesome gem inspite of small probs..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - client_side_validations didn't work and validators hash was empty. When i tried add <%= f.validate %> into form it started to work (and all validators were in hash), but it should work without it. So finally I found out you have to use :symbol notation when creating inputs. E.g. `f.input "name"` didn't work but `f.input :name` did and it's validators were finally automatically loaded.